# Including "And" for multiple variables in single Switch Case

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

I have the following statement, which has been summarised. I was wondering how to show two variables in a single case.

As shown I want pro_st to = 0 when the criteria for both date_avl and pro_qty have been met, but not sure of the correct way to code it.

```
case $insert_pro :
    case $pro_exists_row['date_aval'] == '0000-00-00' : and $sql_data['pro_qty'] == 0 :
    case $sql_data['pro_date_avl'] > date('Y-m-d') :
      $sql_data['pro_st'] = '0' ;
      break ;
    default :
      $sql_data['pro_st'] = '1' ;
```

Any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look like you need an if or possible an if/elseif statement:

```
if (( $pro_exists_row['date_aval'] == '0000-00-00' && $sql_data['pro_qty'] == 0 ) || $sql_data['pro_date_avl'] > date('Y-m-d'))
{
    // This is the first two conditions of you case statement - either of the conditions are met
    $sql_data['pro_st'] = '0' ;
}
else
{
    // This is he default as neither of the others were met...
    $sql_data['pro_st'] = '1' ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a switch statement only to check one var's value, not to check compound conditions like you are trying to do. You will need to use an if statement probably.

Comment: you should have a look at the [Manual on switch case](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) or use an If like suggested by jeroen